# Response code 500 when accesing rest based web services though eclipse

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am trying to invoke a web service from an Eclipse program. But I am getting response code 500 as response. When I access the URL from IE or Mozilla it works fine for me. My sample Eclipse program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   // Use apache commons-httpclient to create the request/response
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("aaa", "aaaa");
   client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, defaultcreds);

   GetMethod method = new GetMethod("http://localhost:8080/usersByID/2039");
   try {
      client.executeMethod(method);
      InputStream in = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
      // Use dom4j to parse the response and print nicely to the output stream
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         out.append(line);
      }
      System.out.println(out.toString());
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

When I opened the link in IE or Mozilla I am getting exact output. The credentials are correct.

Can any one help to overcome this.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling this `Eclipse program`?

Comment: What kind of authentication is used by that server?

Comment: A response code 500 means an error on the server. I would investigate on the server side.

Comment: You should check the error logs on the server side. A few things you might want to verify - that the authorization scope is correct, and that a user agent header is not required.

Comment: @Andremoniy. The authentication is HTTP authentication by the server.This is rest based call. I can directly browse the link of restful URL. I am running the client from eclipse.

Comment: @Henry.  Thanks for clue. I checked logs. I could figure out the solution